# How can I put php code inside php function variable

Tags: php

I have a php function where is variable in which I need to put some php code:

```
function likes() {
$postid = $_GET["videoid"]; 


    $output = '<i  if (userLiked($postid)): class="fa fa-thumbs-up like-btn"  else:  class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up like-btn"  endif  data-id=" echo $postid "></i>
    <span class="likes"> echo getLikes($postid); </span>

    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

    <i  if (userDisliked($postid)):  class="fa fa-thumbs-down dislike-btn"  else:  class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down dislike-btn"  endif  data-id=" echo $postid "></i>
    <span class="dislikes"> echo getDislikes($postid); </span>';
    return $output;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate your HTML string, and your variables (shortened for brevity):

```
 $output = '<i data-id="' .$postid .'"></i><span class="likes">' .getLikes($postid) .'</span>';
```

You might want to look at a templating system, and pass in your variables as props.